# Tablesorter not working on multi select picklist

Tags: jquery, multi-select

```
jQuery('[id$=pbTable] tr').each(function () {

                 if(rowNum<2){

                 //console.log('--tr--');
                 jQuery('td', this).each(function () {
                    //console.log('--td');

                    if(jQuery(this).find("input[type=text], input[type=checkbox]").length != 1){
                        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("hideColumns")){

                            jsonStr = jsonStr + "\""+ index + "\" : " + "{\"sorter\": \"true\"},"; 
                        }

                       // console.log('--*'+jsonStr);
                    }else{
                       jQuery(this).attr('id',counter); 
                       var ColmnTempId= '#'+counter+ '  input';
                       //console.log('--'+jsonStr);
                       //console.log(jQuery(abs).val());

                       if(jQuery(ColmnTempId).is(':input') ){
                           if(!jQuery(ColmnTempId).is(':checkbox')){
                               jsonStr = jsonStr +"\""+ index + "\" : "  + "{\"sorter\": \"inputs\"},";}
                           else{
                               jsonStr =jsonStr + "\""+ index + "\" : " + "{\"sorter\": \"checkboxs\"}";
                           }
                          // console.log('--=='+jsonStr);
                       }
                       counter++;
                    }
                      index++;   
                 });

               }
                rowNum++;
        });
```

The above code is used to determine the type of input and I am not able to make it work for multiple select picklist.

We are not able to sort the multi-select picklist using tablesorter not, we are not able to do since it is creating multiple select boxes - one with OptionGroup and another with select box only. Also I am not able to apply default value in sorter for this since it is creating multiple types. Please help.